# How to access protected inherited non static method in static method(ex main method) of other package?

Tags: java, static-methods, non-static

By creating instance of parent class we can't access its inherited method in other package as it is not direct inheritance. Even directly we cant use non static because our child method is static whereas parent class method isn't. ex

```
package classacees;

public class Thread1 {

protected  double sub(double a, double b) {

return (a - b);

}
```

and...

```
package example;

import classacees.Thread1;

public class Ece extends Thread1 {

        public static  void main(String[] args) {

double n=sub(3,2);  // error -> cant make a static reference to non static method.
System.out.println(n);

}
```

Comment: Could you answer first, why not create `sub` as static and why use a method as static in child class(in your case `main`)?

Comment: It's unclear what your question is.

Comment: instead of double n=sub(3,2), try double n=Thread1.sub(3,2)

Comment: @nullpointer ,My friends asked me the same question and instruct me to not  alter the child class and parent class code.  what should i reply to him?

Comment: @Assafs  still getting error as Thread1 cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can't call an instance method directly like `double n=sub(3,2);` ; for that you need an object.

For your query you can do so by accessing the protected method from the instance of the child class:

```
    public class Ece extends Thread1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ece ece = new Ece();
        double n = ece.sub(4, 9);
        System.out.println(n);
    }

}
```

Hope this helps..